# Statistics 101: T test vs Z test. Sample proportion vs Sample mean

Tags: statistics, sampling, confidence-interval, standard-error

Sorry, I'm just on Khan academy and can't seem to grasp the essence of statistics. Hope to find some help out here.

Both are samples, but why when looking for confidence interval of a:

- sample proportion, we take $\hat{p} \pm Z^*\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$
- sample mean, we take take $\bar{x} \pm t^*{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}$

What I understand:
That both are trying to determine the confidence level that Population mean falls between an interval.

I can see from google that:

> Z-scores are based on your knowledge about the population's standard
> deviation and mean.  T-scores are used when the conversion is made
> without knowledge of the population standard deviation and mean.

But I don't think I properly understand it: what throws me off the statement is that the confidence interval formula $\bar{x} \pm t^*{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}$ still uses S(sampling standard deviation).

Question:

0. Why can't we just take $\bar{x} \pm Z^*\sqrt{\frac{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}{n}}$ as we did $\hat{p} \pm Z^*\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$ ?
1. Both are samples, why does one estimate with $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ while the other uses S (sample standard deviation)?
2. What is the difference between sample proportion and sample mean? Is the former Bernuli distribution and another not?
3. Is the sample proportion confidence interval of a ***single sample*** VS sample mean which is the average of ***multiple samples***?
4. Both are samples, why do we n-1 during t test, but not z test? I get that samples need to -1 to compensate for accuracy, but why didn't we do it for z tests?

Don't feel pressure to answer all the questions, just what you can, perhaps the collective can help me out of this rut. Appreciate it your time reading this!

Comment: The factor $\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}$ is the estimated standard error (standard deviation) of $\hat p$; the estimated standard error of $\overline X$ is $S/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Am I right to say.. $\bar{x}$is the sample mean. $\hat{p}$, is the number of success per sample. They both are means, thus $\bar{x} = \hat{p}$? They seem so similar..

Comment: In the first case you're data consist of counts, presumably from a binomial model, and your question is about proportions of Successes. (It seems you're using a normal approximation to a binomial distribution.) In the second, your data consist of normally distributed measurements, and your question is about normal means. In both cases, you've chosen to look at confidence intervals (CIs), but methods for the best Cis differ somewhat. Given the different circumstances, why would you expect the analysis to be exactly the same? // Try to understand each case on it's own and to make sense of it.

Comment: this helped @BruceET. Thank you!